# How to use html2canvas with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, frontend, next.js, html2canvas

I am using [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/getting-started) in nextjs. As **nextjs** does server side rendering it is difficult to use **html2canvas** in nextjs.
I used the [dynamic](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) library provided by nextjs to import html2canvas,now I don't know how to use html2canvas function after import as written in html2canvas's documentation.

Importing **html2canvas**

```
const html2canvas = dynamic(() => import('html2canvas'),{ssr:false})
```

when I run below step as written in doc,the output of error says

> "html2canvas is not a function"

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
});
```

I want to know how can I use it.

Comment: html2canvas/dist/html2canvas.js does this path exist? and where are you calling html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) { } method

Comment: I changed my path to only 'html2canvas', and i am using the html2canvas inside a function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nextjs dynamic import is used on importing react components. If you want to import a node module you can use normal javascript based dynamic import like below

```
import('html2canvas').then(html2canvas => {
  html2canvas.default(document.body).then(canvas => 
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
  )
}).catch(e => {console("load failed")})
```

Comment: Thanks,this method worked,i will use async await for it.